# How do i use this jquery script on a wordpress site?

Tags: php, jquery

I've been struggling with trying to set a jquery list file on a wordpress site. This is the script and html in a codepen: http://codepen.io/javve/pen/bBfgD

My question is. The examples has html with scripts linked in. Can I copy the html to a custom page or do I need to set them in the header/footer, or enque them? Second question is regarding the jquery:

```
var monkeyList = new List('test-list', {
valueNames: ['name'],
page: 5,
plugins: [ ListPagination({}) ] 
});
```

How do I adapt that to Wordpress? Tried to set it in scripttags in the header, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty simple.

First you have to add a function in your [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)'s functions.php file to register and enqueue your scripts in head using [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook.

```
// Register and enqueue all scripts in head
    function custom_scripts() {

        wp_register_script( 'script_googleapis', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js', false, false, false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script_googleapis' );

        wp_register_script( 'script_listjs', 'http://listjs.com/no-cdn/list.js', false, false, false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script_listjs' );

        wp_register_script( 'script_pagination', 'http://listjs.com/no-cdn/list.pagination.js', false, false, false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script_pagination' );

    }

    // Hook into the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

Then you can call your function to initiate your script in footer using [wp_footer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) hook as following;

```
// Add this in function.php as well

    function call_script_in_footer(){
    ?>
    <script>
    var monkeyList = new List('test-list', {
      valueNames: ['name'],
      page: 3,
      plugins: [ ListPagination({}) ] 
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }

    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'call_script_in_footer' );
```

And thats it. Now you can use your HTML and CSS in what ever template you want.

Comment: Thats brilliant. I was pretty close, but keept fiddling around it. Tat gave me some more understanding of the process! Thanks amillion